# tomcat datasource not checking for valid connection during spring-boot start up?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat7, datasource

I have two spring-boot application.  Application A is using MySQL database configured using HikariDataSource datasource. Application B is using SQL Server database configured using tomcat datasource.

when I supply wrong username for database parameter, Application A does not start up and errors with following exception. However Application B start up fine, but when I make a service call that uses datasource, error is thrown out. why is datasource connection check ignored in the latter?

Note: I have another spring application (Application C), which connects to SQL SERVER using tomcat datasource and that errors out during container start-up if wrong credentials are supplied. It is not a spring-boot application though

Here is my Application A datasource configuration

```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
            HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

            return dataSource;
        }
```

Application B datasource configuration

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(hostdb_driver);
        ds.setUrl(hostdb_url);
        ds.setUsername(hostdb_user);
        ds.setPassword(pass);
        ds.setMaxActive(hostdb_maxActive);
        ds.setMaxIdle(hostdb_maxIdle);
        ds.setInitialSize(hostdb_initialSize);
        ds.setMinIdle(hostdb_minIdle);
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(hostdb_testOnBorrow);
        ds.setTestWhileIdle(hostdb_testWhileIdle);
        ds.setValidationQuery(hostdb_validationQuery);
        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(hostdb_removeAbandoned);
        ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(hostdb_removeAbandonedTimeout);
        ds.setLogAbandoned(hostdb_logAbandoned);
        ds.setValidationInterval(hostdb_validationInterval);
        return ds;
    }
```

Exception message:

```
dg.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:544) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:104) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:338) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:139) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getDefaultDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:198) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getOrDeduceDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:186) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getAdditionalProperties(JpaProperties.java:165) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.access$000(JpaProperties.java:126) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(JpaProperties.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:99) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$425788ff.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$5(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$425788ff$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cee5d89e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$425788ff.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'foobar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:92) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:98) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:438) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The failure is happening in application A because the code that configures Hibernate is making a call to the database during its initialization. Is application B also using Hibernate?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: how do you say Application A is using hibernate during intialization. you are right that Application A uses hibernate. but the error log does not show any hibernate related database initialization.

Comment: Spring Boot's JPA/Hibernate auto-configuration is making a JDBC call as part of determining the default DDL auto behaviour for your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.tomcat/com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc/1.0.8.5/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java#DataSourceProx) of DataSource's super class when you instantiate the DataSource with the No-Args constructor the underlying connection pool is not initialized.

You gotta actually call the `createPool()` method on the DataSource for it to be initialized. I recommend you add the following to your `@Bean` annotation.

`@Bean(initMethod="createPool")`

Comment: how does it work with HikariDataSource dataSource I defined above where I dont have "initMethod"

Comment: HikariDataSource doesn't initialize automatically (see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.java). You must have some other stuff in your app that's being initialized that's trying to use a connection. If you don't believe, use HikariDataSource in application B and shouldn't fail either.